# Image fit inside the div as per mobile device width without stretching

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap and I am trying to fit the images inside the div as per mobile device width without stretching.

```
  <div style="padding:0px!important;overflow:hidden;margin-top: 10px;">
                      <center>
                          <!-- <img src="images/user.png" id="ReguserProfileImage" class="profileimage" style="width:120px;height:121px;" data-bind="attr: { src: image }" />-->
                          <img id="customerProfileImage" src="images/user.png" style="min-width:100%;height:auto" /><br />
                          <div class="activity-photo-upload">
                              <label for="profile-activity-photo">

                                  <a id="OpenView" data-rel="actionsheet" data-role="button" href="#RegProfilePhotoPopUp" style="text-decoration: none;border:none;">
                                      <img src="images/icon-photo.png" class="icon" />
                                  </a>
                              </label>
                          </div>
                      </center>


                  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

it will block every img tag in your source to "stretch" more than maximum screen width.

Comment: Thanks Don for your reply but that didnt help me.  When I change it to max-width: 100% , the image do not even appear. With min-width:100%, it did.

Comment: add `display: block;` for your img tags in combination with `max-width: 100%` or `display: inline-block;` whatever you want

Comment: Don, its not working. When I give min-width:100% and height: auto - that image appears but with a stretch

Comment: Do you happen to have live example of this problem, because when I try this code with `max-width: 100%;` it works like a charm, no strecth and image appears normally.